# PySpark StructField StringType or TimestampType

Tags: pyspark, data-structures, datetime-format

I have a schema `(StructField, StructType)` for pyspark dataframe, we have a date column(value e. g: 2023-10-05). Should this date format data using StringType or TimestampType? I believe StructField only has StringType or TimestampType but not something like DateType.

```
new_schema = [StructField("item_id", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("date", TimestampType(), True),
                     StructField("description", StringType(), True)]
```

I am more prefer using String for date instead of Timestamp for below reason.

1, TimestampType is more used for like streaming data for seconds, milliseconds data where people care about real time. In our case we only need date. String is enough.

2, From consistent perspective, string is more stable to transfer than timestamp.

3, From cast perspective, string to date is more like cast down and timestamp to date is more like cast up, it is safer cast string to date than timestamp to date.

Not sure if my points are valid and appreciate your opinion.

Curious if anyone know why pyspark StructField only has StringType or TimestampType but no dateType?

Comment: it has `DateType` as well, no? and, if the underlying data is string (`"2023-01-01"`), use `StringType` -- [ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html)

Comment: thanks, can you provide your reason?

Comment: yes, spark has `DateType` as well. and choosing the right format for your data type as per need is important. For example, If I didn't need to do a calculation based on date or aggregation, I would go with string data type for date as it takes less memory. also, not sure what you mean by consistency about datatype. data types are consistent but your data may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out it can use DateType.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType
```

So you can you use DateType